# Bootstrap grid not aligned properly

Tags: python, html, django, bootstrap-4

With the django framework I use a loop in my templates to display the image inside my database, I also use the Bootstrap grid to make it clean, but it not working correctly. As you can see the image on at the bottom are not align correctly.

[image]

hmtl

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
            <div class="card-filter" style="width: 10rem;">
                <div class="card-header">
                    Pattern Type
                </div>
                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    {% for pattern in categories %}
                    <li class="list-group-item">{{pattern.name}}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% for photo in photos %}
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-ld-5">
            <div class="card" style="width: 25rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="{{photo.image.url}}" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">Symbol: GBPUSD<br>Pattern: ButterFly Bullish</p>
                    <a href="{% url 'photo' photo.id %}" class="btn btn-dark">View Pattern</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    photos = Photo.objects.all()

    context = {'categories': categories,
               'photos': photos}

    return render(request, "main/home.html", context)
```

Answer (score 1):

You better put all the images in a parent that takes rest of the width after the list on the left, so it should be like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
      <div class="card-filter" style="width: 10rem;">
        <div class="card-header">
          Pattern Type
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
          {% for pattern in categories %}
          <li class="list-group-item">{{pattern.name}}</li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-10">
        {% for photo in photos %}
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
          <div class="card" style="width: 25rem;">
            <img
              class="card-img-top"
              src="{{photo.image.url}}"
              alt="Card image cap"
            />
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">
                Symbol: GBPUSD<br />Pattern: ButterFly Bullish
              </p>
              <a href="{% url 'photo' photo.id %}" class="btn btn-dark"
                >View Pattern</a
              >
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it all put the image on the same columns which is not what I am looking for

Comment: This will make the images in the same container and aligned together, you show me how it looks after the answer and how do you want it to look

Comment: It look like this https://prnt.sc/9TuhAYAalpAO and I want to put them like 2 image per row.

Comment: I think it's because you set width: 25rem not making it take 100%

Comment: No if I remove the width or put it at 100% it doesn't change anything

Comment: can you please share something on codesandbox or fiddle so I can edit myself and see what's wrong